# Redis performance in localhost

Tags: redis, benchmarking, latency

I am trying to check redis performance against mysql in my windows localhost. I am a student and we are learning various things in my school. I have around 1048580 records in  mysql local and I am performing various rest operations. I also have implemented redis to store the values by using springboot cacheable and lettuce. It all works fine but I don't know how to measure the performance to see thaat redis is performing better than mysql. I think it would be easier on a very laarge scale company structure. can I simulate on my local? Also, how to benchmark redis performances on my local for my academic project?

I have tried sending multiple requests in a loop to try to determine performance but don't see much of a difference for localhost - my records. I have tried understanding various commands of redis cli monitoring but don't see much latency.

Comment: Are you aware that Redis includes a benchmark tool that you can use to test it? Read the documentation here: https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: Thanks we tried it but we don't see much difference in mysql vs redis at smaller number of requests. Everything seems to be better with redis at 1000000 plus i guess.

Comment: You should compare the performance under a load as similar as possible to what your application demands.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you are actually testing these `redis` vs `MySQL`. You have to keep in mind that *MySQL* internally use caches, also if you use hibernet then it also does a level of caching. If you do make same get request several time then there would not be any major difference between `redis` and `MySQL` result.

You should compare your result by doing several different operation, like inserting/deleting/getting thousands of different values. Then same operation for identical values etc.